# Using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, select, iteration

I have a large shapefile with 2,5 million points and I would like to create a new field in the attribute table that groups the features into groups of 65000 features.

In other words: Select the first 65000 features, field calculator: = 1, select the next 65000 features, field calculator: = 2 and so on.

Comment: I guess you didn't do the first and most obvious thing and that was to read the Help file? The code for the tool you need to use is all [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F3F8CD77A9F647ABBA678A76ADB86E15).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question/Best answer" model operates. Questions should demonstrate an effort to solve the problem; coding questions should include code. Failure to show *due diligence* toward solving the problem on your own may result in downvotes, closure, or just having your question ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the object identifier (FID or OBJECTID field).  If you divide it by 65000 and convert the result to integer (equivalent to floor), then you will have your groups.

> int(floor(!FID!/65000))

note that you could use ceil() instead of floor() if you prefer to start at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: That's what I was looking for - an easy way for non-programmers. Thank you!